# jQuery / JavaScript Hide an element based on current page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

lets say im on this page

```
http://MyWebSite.com/users
```

and there is a link button on this page lets say

```
<span class="user">
    <a href='{$record->url()}' id="main" class="Small">go to page</a>
</span>
```

If i click on the link it goes to for example

```
http://MyWebSite.com/users/jake
```

So now when im on this page there is **same button exists** and i want to hide it using javascript or jQuery :)

**More info**: The `{$record->url()}` in the link is dynamic goes to a page depending on the user, so i must use `{$record->url()}` in the script to match the current page link
Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think you should hide this with Javascript / jQuery. You should not render this button on the server if the the user is currently on that page.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm on a phone so this is the best I can do for now)

[Maybe something like](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#749aedd7cd1a1560ab952f365c774ea0)....

```
if (window.location.href.replace(location.hash,'') == "http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/") {
  $(".nicole").hide()
} else {
  $(".michael").hide()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery's [equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to hide any elements that had an `href` attribute that pointed to your target page using the following code :

```
// This assumes that the URL will be populated via your server-side code in 
// { ... } braces
$('[href="{$record->url()}"]').hide();
```

likewise, if you just wanted to hide any elements that pointed to the current URL, you could do the same thing via a bit of string concatenation :

```
// This would hide any elements that point to the current URL
$('[href="' + window.location.href + '"]').hide();
```

If you can avoid it though, you may want to consider hiding this using server-side code (i.e. using a conditional to determine when certain elements should / should not be rendered).